# CiviEvent Confirmation Email Displaying Profiles Not Used In Event

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile, email, confirmation

We have created some custom fields/profiles to use with certain CiviEvent registrations. These profiles only display in the event registration when they are selected in the event setup - as expected. However, these profiles appear in the confirmation email despite not being selected for use in the registration. See image below - the highlighted area shows the proflies/custom fields that should NOT appear because they were not used in the event creation. How do I stop them being sent with the confirmation when they are not used?

[image: CiviEvent confirmation email]

Thanks,
Eric
CiviCRM 5.4.1
WP 4.9.8

Comment: This are send from online or offline registration?

Comment: Online registration

Comment: I'd say this is bug. Expected behaviour is that custom fields should only display on an event conformation email when those fields are used in the event registration form. I can't see any rational use case where a participant would want to see field names that don't pertain to th event for which they are registered.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an alternative approach: Try using the extension Event Communication ti send out configurable confirmation emails: https://docs.civicrm.org/eventmessages/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

Eric,
Disabling those fields should remove them from the confirmation email. If you can't disable them (maybe they are from another active event), you can edit the Event Registration Confirmation and Receipt message and target the Event using $event.id (as in {if $event.id != "40"}do such and such{/if} ).
Administer > CiviMail > Message Templates - System Workflow Messages
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To tag on to Greg's response: if disabling the fields and/or modifying the Smarty receipt template won't work for you, check to ensure that the data sets in which those fields reside are specific to the types of events for which you want to use them.  I've seen a lot of clients over the years set up participant fields for all events and then get frustrated later because they 1) appear in emails and 2) make back-end registration a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

We have run into this situation as recently as April 2022, but only in the case that an administrator registers someone for an event from the "back end".

If the user (logged in or not) registers for the event, they get the correct email with only the profile fields used in the registration process.

Also, if the administrator pulls up an incognito browser window and registers as if they were the person they want to register, they receive the expected email.